# trying to find the the gcd using php function return array?

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm trying to write an algorithm to find the GCD ( Greatest common divisor ) but the result of my function is `Array` what I'm doing wrong !! please I don't want another aproche or a ready algorithme copie past I wanna know what i'm doing wrong

```
<?php 

function pgcd($val1, $val2){

    if (!is_numeric($val1) || !is_numeric($val2)){

        return null;
    }

    $i = 1;
    $final = array();

    while($i <= min($val1, $val2)){

        if ($i % $val1 === 0 && $i % $val2 === 0){
            $final[] = $i;

        }

        $i++;
    }

    return $final;
}

echo pgcd(120,420);

 ?>
```

Comment: What you're doing wrong is trying to echo an array..... var_dump or print_r or iterate over it and echo the values

Comment: What your array is returning is __all__ the common denominators.... you'd then need to sort that array (smallest to greatest) and then pop the last value from it, which would be the GCD

Comment: If you're not writing this function just for practice you can take a look at the [GMP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) extension and more precisely the [gmp_gcd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-gcd.php) function it provides.

Comment: you're trying to print an array in a string context. in PHP-land, an array-as-string is the literal word `Array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: you want to find gcd or all common divisors?
If gcd, then you have some errors in your code:
1) replace either `$final = array();` with `$final = null;`, or `return $final;` with `return $final[0];`;
2) replace `if ($i % $val1 === 0 && $i % $val2 === 0)` with `if ($val1 % $i === 0 && $val2 % $i === 0)`;
3) replace `$final[] = $i;` with `$final = $i`;
OR:
1) replace `if ($i % $val1 === 0 && $i % $val2 === 0)` with `if ($val1 % $i === 0 && $val2 % $i === 0)`;
2) replace `return $final;` with `return max($final);`;

Answer (score 0):

Returned $final is an array. For print array use print_r(YOUR_VALUE). if u using 'echo' u can print only string value, not array;

Comment: the same story I get Array ( )

Comment: this is becouse you condition is not perform
if ($i % $val1 === 0 && $i % $val2 === 0) and you return the empty array. So program write you array() becouse he is empty... try to use var_dump and you will see that